# CA Root Certificate with same subject

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Let's assume I have issued two root certificates for my domain - a RSA and a ECDSA one. Both have the same subject. As far as I know, the subject does not have to be unique.

Do crypto libraries such as OpenSSL cycle through all installed certificates when validating a certificate chain? Or is having two root certificates with the same subject installed a problem since it might only check against one of the root certificates?

Example: Let's say Server *S* sends its ECDSA leaf certificate and its whole ECDSA chain to Client *C*. Does *C* choose the ECDSA root certificate for validating the chain automatically? Or does *C* potentially run into issues because it chooses the root certificate it validates against only based on the subject name and might pick the RSA root certificate?

Comment: I think they also go by the AKI: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.1. What happens if you have a malicious root cert with the same subject *and* KI in your CA store, I do not know.

Comment: Okay, so there should be no issues if the two certificates have different AKIs ?

Comment: It depends on particular library. I can speak for MS CryptoAPI: it uses SKI/AKI pairs to bind certificates in chain. As long as certs have different AKIs, then there will be no issue.

Comment: Thank you :) That's good to know.